# Mac Shell script get home directory

Tags: macos, bash, cp, home-directory

I need to get the home directory in my shell script so my coworkers can run it. What my shell does is really simple, it only copy some directories to another. I've used:

> $HOME,
>   $(whoami)
>   even this:
>   ABSPATH=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd),

but when I use the variable like this:

> DIR= $ABSPATH/folder/afolder/bfolder/

and run it I receive this:

> /Users/theUser/Desktop/FusionTest.command: line 14: /Users/theUser/Desktop/folder/afolder/bfolder: is a directory
>   Copying  to 
>   usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
>          cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
>   logout
>   [Process completed]

I'm using the command cp -r to copy all files and directories.

Whay I am missing? or how can I do this??

Comment: You should always quote expansions when writing shell scripts. So, use `"$HOME"` and not just `$HOME`.

Comment: one important point is the user in question may be another user not self so $HOME is not valid ... a common use case on server side

Answer (score 9):

As the error message implies `-r` is the incorrect flag for recursive copying. The flag you want is `-R` (flags are case-sensitive). As for the home directory, `$HOME` should always work.

Comment: The GNU version of `cp` permits `-r` as well, but this is not standard and won't be found on OS X, even if many bits of sample code might be written that way.

Comment: @sorpigal - looks POSIX to me - http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/cp.html

Comment: @jordanm: That defines `-r`, but doesn't require it to do anything useful ("If the -r option was specified, the behavior is implementation-defined.").  I'd avoid it...

Comment: one important point of OP is the user in question may be another user not self so $HOME is not valid

Answer (score 7):

Talk about several things here:

1. How Macs handle `HOME` directories and a way to retrieve the actual `HOME` directory if it has been unset.
2. How to use command line parameters correctly because the GNU `cp` command on Linux allows you to do it the wrong way, and that has caused a lot of problems.
3. How to use `set -xv` for debugging in your script. This will help you debug about 90% of the shell script errors you get.
4. What I think is actually wrong in your script. Unfortunately, this is a wild guess due to a lack of information, but it's a pretty good guess.

---

### How Macs Handle Home Directories

Mac OS X is a true Unix version. In fact, it's even more Unix than Linux. Because of this, it should be fairly compatible with almost all systems.

The Mac home directory are stored under the `/Users` directory. In the default BASH shell that Mac uses (and even in the old Turbo Csh), you can use `~` as an alias to the `$HOME`.

```
 $ echo "$HOME"   # Use quotes around directory and file names to avoid 
 $                # problems with white spaces.
 $ echo ~         # Echos the `$HOME` directory.
```

If someone changed the `HOME` environment variable, you can use `~userName` to get the *correct* value of the `HOME` directory:

```
$ echo $HOME
/Users/david
HOME=/tmp
$ echo $HOME
/tmp
$ echo ~
/tmp
$ echo ~david
 /Users/david
$ HOME=~david   #Fixed!
```

### Command Line Parameters

The error probably doesn't have anything to do with the *Macness* of your computer. It's probably a standard problem you'd find on almost any computer. The Mac's `cp` command takes either the `-r` or `-R` command. Unlike GNU's `cp` which is found on Linux systems, the Mac handles the command line parameters *correctly*.

For example, on Linux, this is acceptable:

```
$ cp "$dir" "$dir2" -r
```

On Unix systems, that would probably fail. You need the `-r` parameter after the command:

```
$ cp -r "$dir" "$dir2"
```

If you're doing the `cp` command as in the first example, it won't work on Unix and won't work on a Mac.

### Debugging Shell Scripts

Now, that we got some preliminaries out of the way, let's look how to debug your problem...

Put `set -xv` before line #14 (maybe a few lines before just to be sure). This turns on script debugging. The `-x` parameter will echo the command line with interpolations before executing the line. This way, you can see what the actual command is being executed.

The `-v` parameter will echo the line *as is* without interpolation. That way, you can see what the command looked like and maybe detect an error in the setting of an environment variable.

Here's a simple script:

```
 name="David"
 echo "Hello $name!"
```

Executing the script, we get:

```
 $ test.sh
 Hello David!
 $
```

Now, I'll do this:

```
 set -xv
 name="David"
 echo "Hello $name!"
 set +xv     #Turns off the -xv flags
```

Now, I'll get this:

```
 $ ./test.sh
 name="David"
 + name=David
 echo "Hello $name!"
 + echo 'Hello David!'
 Hello David!
```

Another neat trick is to set `PS4` to "`${LINENO}:`". That will prepend each line with the line number rather than just a `+` as above:

### The Possible Solution

I have a feeling that the problem is that you have a directory name with spaces in it. Quote directory and file names to prevent these spaces from causing you problems:

```
my_pictures=$HOME/"My Pictures"
cp -R $my_pictures $target     #Won't work due to the space between "My" & "Pictures"
cp -R "$my_pictures" "$target" #The quotes solve the problem.
```

### Conclusions

Don't worry about your Mac being *different*. It's just another Unix system. Make sure that you're using the command line parameters correctly `cp -R $dir1 $dir2` and not `cp $dir $dir2 -R`. Use `set -xv` to help you locate the errors, and get into the habit of quoting your environment variables since a space or tab in the environment variable's value could cause the program to fail.

---

#### Note on Mac OS X - Lion

According to the manpage, `-r` is no longer documented as an option. However it does work. According to the man page:

> Historic versions of the cp utility had a -r option. This implementation supports that option; however, its use is strongly discouraged, as it does not correctly copy special files, symbolic links, or fife's.

However, `cp -R` should work on both Linux and is documented in Mac OS X as the recursive copy flag.

Comment: OSX `cp` on at least 10.7.4 doesn't recognize the `-r` flag. I remember this being the case earlier as well.

Comment: I just checked. It uses `cp -R` instead of `cp -r`, but says in the bottom "_Historic versions of the cp utility had a -r option.  This implementation supports that option; however, its use is strongly discouraged, as it does not correctly copy special files, symbolic links, or fife's._". Basically, using `cp -r` does work, but isn't encouraged. GNU on Linux supports both `-r` and `-R`. Use `-R` then.

Comment: @You BTW, thank you for pointing it out that `cp -r` is apparently no longer encouraged on Mac OS X. I've been using it since `cp` started using it about 15 years ago (before that, you used `cpio` to copy directories). I see that `cp -r` works on my system and I have 10.7.4, but I also upgraded from Snow Leopard, so it could be a result of that. You can use `cp -R` instead, and that works on Linux too. I changed my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @DavidW. In an Automator "Run Shell Script" action `$HOME` is not set. How would you get it without hardcoding the username?

Comment: @mb21 I don't use Automator, so I'm not sure what Automator does when it runs. Does `logname` or `whoami` return anything? You could use that to get the user name, then use `finger` to get the $HOME directory.

Comment: @mb21 I just created an Automator script, and it was able to use both `$HOME` and `~` as the Home directory. How are you running the Automator script?

Comment: @DavidW. You're right, now it's working for me as well! Strange, at first I could use `$HOME` only when I clicked the "Run" button but not when I invoked it through the "Services" Menu, but now it's working there as well :)

Comment: "Use of this option is strongly discouraged as the
     behavior is implementation-dependent.  In FreeBSD, -r is a synonym for
     -RL and works the same unless modified by other flags.  Historical imple-
     mentations of -r differ as they copy special files as normal files while
     recreating a hierarchy." https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cp&sektion=1#end

Answer (score 2):

I don't like ~ in scripts and $HOME fails sometimes depending on the shell you're using - maybe not on OSX, but I don't care..

Somewhere somehow the system has a record of where a user's home directory is and $HOME is set from that.

Specifically, I am usually trying to find the home dir of another user (and again not a fan of ~ abbreviations in scripts - call it preference)
For OSX, I use this --

```
 finger $username | awk '/^Directory/ {print $2}'
```

Everywhere else, I usually grep /etc/passwd, but thinking on it, finger would probably be more universal.

This is my quick and dirty answer. There will be a better solution if you know OSX internal better - but care factor? This works for me

Comment: Is there a way to make this work if the user's directory has a space in it?

Answer (score 1):

$HOME should be set, but it is not guaranteed. It is possible for a user to override this variable. Another option is to use `getent`.

```
IFS=: read -r _ _ _ _ _ homedir _ < <(getent passwd myuser)
echo "$homedir"
```

Comment: Use this to find the user's home directory `dscl . -read /users/$user | grep NFSHomeDirectory`

Comment: You don't need to `grep` here. To combine these two together: `IFS=": " read -r _ homedir < <(dscl . -read /users/$user NFSHomeDirectory); echo $homedir`.